# How to drop a primary key without dropping a foreign key referencing it?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have tried "nocheck constraint all" in sql server, but could not drop the column.

```
alter table temp
nocheck constraint all
drop constraint [PK__temp3__DC501A3]
```

Comment: You can't. You need to drop the foreign key.

Comment: @MartinSmith but "nocheck constraint all" is used to disable checking constraints over table. and "with check check constraint all" is used to enable the constraints over table.I hope there is solution for sure.

Comment: As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.100).aspx) says, a foreign key must reference either a primary key or a unique constraint. So you cannot drop the primary key, because then the foreign key would not be referencing anything, which is not allowed.